# Como aumentar o tempo da sessão no phpMyAdmin no Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Quando estou desenvolvendo um sistema, costumo deixar meu `phpmyadmin` aberto.

Daí, quando passa um tempo, essa mensagem abaixo aparece:

[image: phpMyAdmin expirando a sessão. Como aumentar o tempo?]

Como posso configurar meu `phpmyadmin` de maneira que eu possa aumentar esse tempo de sessão (ou removê-lo)?

Comment: Seu phpmyadmin é em um servidor online ou local?

Comment: Como eu disse, é desenvolvimento - é local :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se irá usar apenas em desenvolvimento local eu recomendo não usar autenticação para facilitar o trabalho

Para isto vá até a pasta do `phpmyadmin` por exemplo `/var/www/phpmyadmin` ou `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` e procure o arquivo `config.inc.php`.

Se não encontrar a pasta, pode tentar o seguinte comando no (acaso seja linux - fonte: [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=832872&p=5210536#post5210536)):

```
locate phpmyadmin
```

E modifique as linhas para algo como:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Note que a linha permite você se logar sem autenticação:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Deve se definir o login e senha do usuário desejado (geralmente o root):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

## phpMyAdmin versão 4.4+

A partir da versão 4.4 (versão estável) as variáveis de configuração mudaram um pouco:

```
/* Define o tipo de autenticacao */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

/* parametros do servidor */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* dados do banco e do usuario que ira manipular os dados */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root'; //usario do banco
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = ''; //senha do banco
```

> **Nota:** Desta maneira não irá expirar a sessão e também não irá precisar fazer autenticação (não use isto em ambiente de produção)

Comment: Onde fica esse arquivo?

Comment: O exemplo que você postou é para remover a senha ou é para aumentar/remover o tempo de expiração da sessão no PHPMYADMIN? Porque, se for pra remover a senha, eu teria que reconfigurar todos os sistemas locais, pois todos utilizaram a senha do usuário "root"

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu editei a resposta e editei a pergunta devido a sua duvida sobre a localização do arquivo.

Comment: O exemplo é pra não expirar o tempo e não precisar fazer o login. @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 4):

Ops! Parece que a solução também já estava no própio `phpmyadmin` :)

Veja a imagem:

[image: Validade do cookie de início da sessão]

Eu apenas preciso alterar o valor de "Validade do cookie de início da sessão" para um número maior.

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de resolver é alterando o arquivo de configuração do PHP (php.ini). Procure pela linha que contenha o código abaixo:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime =
```

coloque o valor que desejar (em segundos). Se quiser um dia, por exemplo, coloque 86400 que equivale a 24 * 60 * 60, isto é:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

Depois, no arquivo config.inc.php do seu phpmyadmin, altere ou insira uma linha com o código

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] =
```

com o mesmo valor de session.gc_maxlifetime, ou seja:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;
```