# não consigo logar no phpmyadmim

Tags: wampserver

eu estou usando um computador com Windows7 e baixei o wampserver dai quando eu vou entrar no myadmim ele pede uma conta eu eu não sei que conta é essa.
dai eu ja entrei em configurações do phpmyadmim para mudar a senha e nao deu certo por que ele fala pra eu colocar o usuario assim: exemple@localhost e a senha yes
e quando eu coloco isso nao entra mesmo assim
oque eu faço?

Answer (score 1):

O acesso padrão **do mysql** no WampServer é login `root` e a senha em vazio.

Você não tem como mudar o login e senha do phpmyadmin, porque eles **não são do phpmyadmin**, o phpmyadmin é um gerenciador, ele pode acessar até bancos de dados remotos (em outros servidores ou máquinas), **leia isto**:

- [Qual a diferença entre o MySQL e o phpMyAdmin?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115691/3635)

Se mudou algo no `config.inc.php` do phpmyadmin, restaure ao original, isso deve concertar as coisas, agora estando em *localhost* ou seja ambiente de desenvolvimento, você pode configurar pro phpmyadmin se autologar ao seu banco local, como expliquei esta resposta:

- [Como aumentar o tempo da sessão no phpMyAdmin no Ubuntu?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73678/3635)